# How can a range of values be identified for the ListFillRange option of creating a list box (form control)

Tags: excel, vba

I am in a similar situation as cazzzac who asked the same titled question on May 8, 2014.  I may be more of a newbie than he as I don't understand the answer he received as something that could be done in a VBA macro.
My code:

```
Dim rngList as Range
'
' Make list box of physician names
'
    Set rngList = Range(Range("DA1"), Range("DA1").End(xlDown))
    ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(2.25, 1.5, 188.25, 120).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = "'How to Use'!rngList"  <<<---
        .LinkedCell = "$A$1"
        .MultiSelect = xlNone
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
```

The "<<<---" marked line makes "'How to Use'!rngList" as the Input range for the List Box (Form Control), which obviously does nothing useful.
Changing that line to:

```
    .ListFillRange = "'How to Use'!Range(Range("DA1"), Range("DA1").End(xlDown))"
```

is also useless as the second quote character is interpreted as the end of the string.

Comment: You can use double quotes (`""`) to denote quote characters within a string, or insert characters using their ASCII values, using the [`Chr`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465.aspx), if that is your only problem

Comment: Thanks.  Completely forgot the double-quote approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rngList As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet, lb As Object

Set sht = ActiveSheet

Set rngList = sht.Range(sht.Range("D1"), sht.Range("D1").End(xlDown))

Set lb = sht.ListBoxes.Add(2.25, 1.5, 188.25, 120)
With lb
    .ListFillRange = rngList.Address()
    .LinkedCell = sht.Range("A1").Address()
    .MultiSelect = xlNone
    .Display3DShading = False
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  Worked like a charm!